# workflow for an Item added to the list

Tags: workflow

Could you please help me in creating a workflow for one Item in the list. I need to get a notification email once I add an Item to a specific column and this column contain number and letter.

Answer (score 1):

You will need SharePoint Designer installed on your computer.

Creating workflow:

1. Open SharePoint designer
2. Open your site
3. Go to Workflows
4. Click 'List Workflow' on ribbon and select your list

[image]

5. Add 'Send email' action

   [image]
6. The following block will be added to your workflow:

[image]

7. Configure 'Send email' action to use created by field for determining recipient emails
8. In the "Field from source" select "Created by" and for "Return field as" dropdown select email address. Also define the body block for the letter. You can use different lookups there, for example inserting values from the item or item URL or whatever.
9. Now go to 'Workflow Settings'

[image]

10. Setup workflow to start whenever item is added or created

[image]

11. Publish